# hover frame on image with css animation

Tags: animation

I am trying to produce an animated frame which should appear on hover using css. 
I have managed to get so far with the animation but unfortunately I can't seem to get this onto different images. The dream is to be able to place this code on to any image any size and have it work. Help is need please, Thanks.

```
<style type="text/css">
figure {
position: relative;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 10px;
width:300px;
height: 220px;
background-color: #333;
text-align: center;
}
figure.effect :before,
figure.effect :after {
position: absolute;
content: '';
opacity: 0;
}
figure.effect :before {
 top: 50px;
 right: 30px;
 bottom: 50px;
left: 30px;
 border-top: 1px solid #fff;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
 -webkit-transform: scale(0,1);
transform: scale(0,1);
-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
transform-origin: 0 0;
}
figure.effect :after {
 top: 30px;
 right: 50px;
 bottom: 30px;
left: 50px;
border-right: 1px solid #fff;
border-left: 1px solid #fff;
-webkit-transform: scale(1,0);
transform: scale(1,0);
-webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
transform-origin: 100% 0;
}
figure.effect :before,
figure.effect :after {
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
}
figure.effect:hover :before,
figure.effect:hover :after {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transform: scale(1);
transform: scale(1);
}
figure.effect:hover:after{
-webkit-transition-delay: 0.15s;
transition-delay: 0.15s;
} 
</style>
<body>
<img src="mobile.jpg">
<figure class="effect">
    <figcaption>
        <a href="work.html"></a>
    </figcaption>           
</figure>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you are looking for?

html

```
<div class="image"><!-- image can be placed here -->
<div class="imagehover">text
</div></div>
```

css

```
.image {    
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
background-color: red;
line-height: 400px;
}
.imagehover{
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
background:; 
opacity:0;
text-align: center;
font-size:20px;
transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.image:hover .imagehover { 
transition: 0.2s;
opacity:1;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
text-align:justify; 
color:white;
font-size:25px; 
font-weight:700; 
font-family: "apercu",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; 
text-align: center;
line-height: 400px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d6yhnmnf/5/